# No changes in model, should EF migration create empty empty Up() Down() methods? Or no migration at all?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using EntityFrameworkCore Code First to create my SQL migration scripts.

After every change in my model, I run `Add-Migration changeInModel` and a corresponding XXXXXXXX_changeInModel.cs file is being generated in my Migrations folder.

If I don't make any change in my models AND I run `Add-Migration noChangeInModel` , I was assuming (out of nowhere) no generation of  XXXXXX_noChangeInModel.cs

However, EF Core is creating a XXXXXX_noChangeInModel.cs with an empty Up and Down methods.

Is that supposed to be the expected behavior? Or should EF Core just skip the generation of an empty .cs file? I can't find any reference to this in the documentation.

I have taken my main project and stripped out all the code up to the bare minimum to find out whether is the behavior or some sort of bug in my configuration.

Below the minimum core to reproduce generating empty Up/Down methods with no change in models, with the following Nuget packages:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.6
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.2.6
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.2.6
- Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.0

```
namespace TestingEFCore
{
    public class ApplicationDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<BloggingContext>
    {
        public BloggingContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var connectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=TEST2;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            return new BloggingContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }

    public class BloggingContext : DbContext
    {
        public BloggingContext(DbContextOptions<BloggingContext> options)
            : base(options)
        { }

        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    }

    public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I would expect no XXXXXX_noChangeInModel.cs being generated, but a I get migrations with empty Up/Down methods. I can't find the documentation to describe this use case.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is expected behavior. Consider the case when you have no changes in model but you need to add some data in your db like this

```
public partial class your_migration : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.Sql(@"your sql");            
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.Sql(@"sql to clean up data");
    }
}
```

Without an empty migration for no changes in model generated it would be impossible to obtain such migration.